# -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString _encodingCantBeStoredInEightBitCFString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios6, nsattributedstring

I have an App on the AppStore which is working on iOS6 & iOS7.

I have a user on iOS6 that keep getting a crash.
I have no clue of what he is doing on the App to get the crash, and the backtraces I get on Crashlytics are not helping me...

Do Someone know what is causing a `[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString _encodingCantBeStoredInEightBitCFString]: unrecognized selector` ??
It seems to only happen on iOS6...

Thank you in advance !

(I can't add some code because I don't know what's causing this, and hope someone did succeed to resolve this issue)

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x33ee82a3 __exceptionPreprocess + 162
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3bb4497f objc_exception_throw + 30
2  CoreFoundation                 0x33eebe07 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 170
3  CoreFoundation                 0x33eea531 ___forwarding___ + 392
4  CoreFoundation                 0x33e41f68 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5  CoreFoundation                 0x33ecb49d __CFStringCheckAndReplace + 484
6  CoreFoundation                 0x33e430a7 -[__NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:] + 22
7  Foundation                     0x3475687f -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:] + 362
8  Foundation                     0x34756295 -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:attributes:] + 228
9  UIKit                          0x35d84d5f -[NSAttributedString(UILabelAdditions) _ui_synthesizeAttributedSubstringFromRange:usingDefaultAttributes:] + 86
10 UIKit                          0x35d84ab5 -[UILabel _synthesizedAttributedText] + 148
11 UIKit                          0x35cfacbd -[UILabel _textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:includingShadow:] + 132
12 UIKit                          0x35cfac27 -[UILabel textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:] + 54
13 UIKit                          0x35d611c7 -[UILabel _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:] + 158
14 UIKit                          0x35f280a7 -[UILabel intrinsicContentSize] + 90
15 UIKit                          0x3612c987 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _generateContentSizeConstraints] + 30
16 UIKit                          0x3612c939 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _updateContentSizeConstraints] + 72
17 UIKit                          0x3612ef3d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraints] + 84
18 UIKit                          0x3612ee47 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 182
19 CoreFoundation                 0x33e2e74d CFArrayApplyFunction + 176
20 UIKit                          0x3612edfb -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 106
21 CoreFoundation                 0x33e2e74d CFArrayApplyFunction + 176
22 UIKit                          0x3612edfb -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 106
23 CoreFoundation                 0x33e2e74d CFArrayApplyFunction + 176
24 UIKit                          0x3612edfb -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 106
25 CoreFoundation                 0x33e2e74d CFArrayApplyFunction + 176
26 UIKit                          0x3612edfb -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 106
27 CoreFoundation                 0x33e2e74d CFArrayApplyFunction + 176
28 UIKit                          0x3612edfb -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 106
29 CoreFoundation                 0x33e2e74d CFArrayApplyFunction + 176
30 UIKit                          0x3612edfb -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 106
31 CoreFoundation                 0x33e2e74d CFArrayApplyFunction + 176
32 UIKit                          0x3612edfb -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 106
33 CoreFoundation                 0x33e2e74d CFArrayApplyFunction + 176
34 UIKit                          0x3612edfb -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 106
35 Foundation                     0x3489c883 -[NSISEngine withAutomaticOptimizationDisabled:] + 166
36 UIKit                          0x36128de1 -[UIWindow(UIConstraintBasedLayout) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 124
37 UIKit                          0x35cf33f3 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 66
38 UIKit                          0x35d9292d -[UITableViewHeaderFooterView setFrame:] + 188
39 UIKit                          0x35eedf51 __105-[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _sectionHeaderView:withFrame:forSection:floating:reuseViewIfPossible:]_block_invoke_0 + 144
40 UIKit                          0x35d3e0a9 +[UIView(Animation) _performWithoutAnimation:] + 72
41 UIKit                          0x35d926cb -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _sectionHeaderView:withFrame:forSection:floating:reuseViewIfPossible:] + 242
42 UIKit                          0x35d925d3 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _sectionHeaderViewWithFrame:forSection:floating:reuseViewIfPossible:] + 58
43 UIKit                          0x35d22041 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleHeadersAndFootersNow:] + 1600
44 UIKit                          0x35d2050b -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1814
45 UIKit                          0x35d377cf -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 206
46 UIKit                          0x35cf3803 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 258
47 QuartzCore                     0x35a9dd8b -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 214
48 QuartzCore                     0x35a9d929 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 460
49 QuartzCore                     0x35a9e85d CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
50 QuartzCore                     0x35a9e243 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 238
51 QuartzCore                     0x35a9e051 CA::Transaction::commit() + 316
52 QuartzCore                     0x35a9deb1 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 60
53 CoreFoundation                 0x33ebd6cd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
54 CoreFoundation                 0x33ebb9c1 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 276
55 CoreFoundation                 0x33ebbd17 __CFRunLoopRun + 742
56 CoreFoundation                 0x33e2eebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
57 CoreFoundation                 0x33e2ed49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
58 GraphicsServices               0x379ab2eb GSEventRunModal + 74
59 UIKit                          0x35d44301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
60 MyApp                          0x00029087 main (main.m:19)
61 libdyld.dylib                  0x3bf7bb20 start
```

Comment: It's somewhere where you're doing something funky with a label and the system thinks it can use an attributed string to achieve the effect you requested.

Answer (score 1):

Sending an NSAttributedString to the text method of UILabel caused this for me. Easily fixed by using attributedText as I should have.

Answer (score 0):

My workmate had same experience, too. Because he code like this
`@property (copy) NSMutableAttributeString * a;` It's obviousely wrong. So, please check your code~. Maybe you have use copy method somewhere...